# mounting android phone as serial com port device in PC

Tags: android, serial-port

As an R&D work, I am trying to mount my android phone as serial com port device in windows, similar to other COM port devices.

What is the configuration I need to do in my android phone?

I am trying to send "hello world " from my pc to android phone via USB.

Windows I have termite software for serial write. I have referred many websites, still, I couldn't get any clarity.
Can someone please advise me on this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Send hello world and do what with it?  A phone is not a COM device, you aren't going to send it a message and see it printed on the screen or something like that.  The entire concept of what you're trying to do it kind of broken.

Comment: @GabeSechan: thanks for your suggestion. Actual plan is to simulate data from pc to phone via UART protocol.So PC to Phone using uart(USB) is my cocentration.
Can't we mount the phone as a COM device by any configuration without additional UART converters?